# How to have chrome app on my kids iPads?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, google-chrome

I downloaded chrome on my iPad from the App Store, & I would like the kids to have it on their iPad mini which is connected to my account, how can I do that?  When I go to the App Store on their iPad it won't show the "free-install" button. What can I do?

Comment: What does it show exactly?

Comment: when I click onto the chrome app it doesn't allow me to download it on my kids iPad. It gives me the chrome symbol, below that details/reviews/related. No place to hit download.

Answer (score 1):

Two things could interfere with the download.

1. Parental restrictions would suppress Chrome if your children's iPad doesn't allow that app due to age limits or explicit content filters.
2. Not using the same AppleID on both devices.

To address the restrictions, go to the settings app and inspect / relax any restrictions to get that one app installed. To address the Apple ID, take both devices and sign out of the App Store from the settings app. Then sign them both in with the same account. At that point, the purchase history for both should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

On the tabs in the App Store at the bottom of the screen, click 'More' then 'Purchased' or 'Purchased'. The Google Chrome app should appear here if you have previously downloaded it with the same Apple ID.

Let me know if help is needed.

Comment: I know how to do that, in fact have and when I click onto the chrome app it doesn't allow me to download it on my kids iPad. It gives me the chrome symbol, below that details/reviews/related. No place to hit download.